# Strange for loop syntax

Tags: php, for-loop

I've been programming in php for about 2 years now.

I just stumbled into this for loop:

```
    // Check the URI namespace for a context
    $wsDir = basename(dirname(__FILE__));
    $uriArr = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    for (
        $i = 0, $uriSize = sizeof($uriArr);
        $i < $uriSize && $uriArr[$i] != $wsDir && $i++;
    );

    $i++;
    self::$executionContext = isset($uriArr[$i]) && !empty($uriArr[$i]) && substr($uriArr[$i], 0, 1) != '?'
        ? strtoupper($uriArr[$i]) : 'SOAP';
```

and I have no idea how this is supposed to work.

Can someone explain this to me ?

Comment: If you find the person that wrote that, I have a few choice words for them :P.

Comment: Looks like it's finding the end position of the base directory in the URI. A for loop doesn't need a block, it will execute the first expression unconditional once. It'll then execute the second condition whilst it is true. The third condition is empty, meaning it's executing nothing.

Comment: The [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) does show in example 4 that it can be used without a statement block.

Comment: @R.Chappell if you look closely, you will see that the for loop conditions are 2, not 3. As far as I can see, the only idea of this is to initialize `$i`

Comment: @VasilShaddix at the end of second statement in the for loop is a `;` which indicates that there are 3 statements, it's just the third one is completely empty.

Comment: readability my ass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coming late, but none seems to have cached this : this for loop is equivalent to :

```
$i = 1;
```

Why ? Because in the condition part of the for loop, you have 3 conditions that are bound with `AND`:

```
$i < $uriSize 
&&
$uriArr[$i] != $wsDir 
&&
$i++;
```

In the first iteration, `$i++` evaluates to 0 which is equivalent to false, and is incremented only after. So the loop stops after only one iteration, and `$i` is 1, and you have a bug. Unless it's a typo in your code...

Comment: :-O You are a genius!

Comment: Coming late from my part as well. I was looking at the code after that and I saw it as well. Thank you. This is actually the correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

It is just a normal three-part for loop without its main statement and an empty third part.

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php):

> ```
> for (expr1; expr2; expr3)
>       statement
> ```
>
> The first expression (`expr1`) is evaluated (executed) once unconditionally at the beginning of the loop.
>
> In the beginning of each iteration, `expr2` is evaluated. If it evaluates to TRUE, the loop continues and the nested statement(s) are executed. If it evaluates to FALSE, the execution of the loop ends.
>
> At the end of each iteration, `expr3` is evaluated (executed).

So:

```
for (
    # initializes two variables
    $i = 0, $uriSize = sizeof($uriArr);

    # conditional, expr2
    $i < $uriSize && $uriArr[$i] != $wsDir && $i++;

    # no expr3
);
```

If the `expr2` evaluates to true the loop continues. Of course there is no statement or block to execute, so it just jumps to the next iterarion, meaning `expr2` will be executed repeatedly until it evaluates to false at some point.

As pointed out by R. Chappell in the comments, this is probably to find a position in a string. You could rewrite this with a similar logic but in a more "descriptive" way:

```
$uriSize = sizeof($uriArr)

for ($i = 0; $i < $uriSize; $i++) {
    if ($uriArr[$i] == $wsDir) break;
}

# now $i will be the index of the first $wsDir occurrence in the $uriArr array
```

Comment: This actually, made it really clear to me. Thank you @sidyll

Comment: Thanks @VasilShaddix , happy that it is more clear now. I just updated the answer with a rewrite

Comment: Thanks for the mention :)

Answer (score 2):

This is another example (not an answer as such) of using a for without a third statement. It's a little clearer than the original question.

```
for ($i=0; $i >= $i++ && $i <= 10; /* third statement */ );
echo $i;
```

This will basically count to 10 and echo it out, and it's only made possible with the [increment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) operator in PHP.

First we set `$i` to zero;

Second we check and increment `$i` to ensure it's equal to or greater than itself whilst less than or equal to 10.

Third we do nothing... no point really...

However, normal people would write the same thing as:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++);
echo $i;
```

You'll have to imagine a better use case though and yes you can just do `$i = 10;` but it doesn't go as far as to explaining the question.